# How to query Firebase for value between two keys

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

How can i search firebase data with a value, i want to get the data if the value comes in between the two keys

Example

If user enter any number between 1 to 5 return the below data,

```
"start" : "1",
"end" : "5",
```

"end" key can be empty, the array i have in my firebase database is below

```
"classdata" : [ null, {
      "-L4VflG9efJfNOk0ETjK" : {
        "start" : "1",
        "end" : "2",
        "classdate" : 1517761011016,
        "commentator" : "",
        "description" : "",
        "id" : 1517745488337,
        "title" : "12"
      },
      "-L4WUbRH46l3pIcwDC2z" : {
        "start" : "3",
        "end" : "",
        "classdate" : 1518961333727,
        "commentator" : "",
        "description" : "",
        "id" : 1517759080685,
        "title" : "5"
      },
      "-L4WbgyUB7MRVUzBNJM3" : {
        "start" : "4",
        "end" : "6",
        "classdate" : 1518975293250,
        "commentator" : "",
        "description" : "",
        "id" : 1517761201012,
        "title" : "2"
      },
      "-L5cxhQzDkEHrFi6J5Mf" : {
        "start" : "7",
        "end" : "",
        "classdate" : 1519010573333,
        "commentator" : "",
        "description" : "",
        "id" : 1518958204014,
        "title" : "1"
      },
```

Comment: [Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries) offers this compound query ability, e.g. `.where("start", ">", 1).where("end", "<", 5)`

Comment: if the answer helped you, please upvote it and mark it as correct so others know that it is helpful, thank you! @rashidnk

Answer (score 1):

You can only query on one child so either `start` or `end` child.

What you can do is this:

```
ref.orderByChild("start").equalTo("4").on(...){...};
```

The above will give you the values when start=4

```
ref.orderByChild("start").limitToFirst(5).on(...){..};
```

this will give you the first 5 of child `start`

```
ref.orderByChild("start").startAt("1").endAt("5").on(..){..};
```

Answer (score 0):

As @Peter Haddad said "firebase only allows to query on one field" so what you can do to solve your issue is:

```
firebase.database().ref('classdata')
  .orderByChild('start')
  .startAt(1)
  .once('value', function (snapshot) {
    snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
      var childKey = childSnapshot.key;
      var childData = childSnapshot.val();

      // Here you filter by your second field
      if (childData.end === '' || childData.end <= 5) {
        ...
      }
    });
  })
```

You can find [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/lists-of-data#sorting_and_filtering_data) more documentation about how to filter data in firebase.

---

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26700924/query-based-on-multiple-where-clauses-in-firebase?answertab=active#tab-top) you can find some really good approaches to resolve your issue.

Comment: Your code doesn't order the child nodes by anything yet, which means that the `startAt` and `endAt` clauses filter by priority.